# Проблема при регистрации и авторизации пользователей

Tags: php, регистрация, symfony4

Symfony 4.4.7 (env: dev, debug: true)

Добрый день,  при регистрации получаю следуюшую ошибку

```php
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.
```

из профайлера:

Origin `fos_user_registration`

Cause:

```php
Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken {#1163 ▼
  -id: "registration"
  -value: "0WBtDlEB0_RCltyWmMlCYa8Mxxm3mVwzsZOTExd2q8A"
}
```

из dev.log:

```php
security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []
```

Не могу найти причину этот же код работает нормально у моего коллеги.
на странице когда проверяю токен он есть

```html
<input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration__token" name="fos_user_registration[_token]" value="AGzhJ_A73Y1fRIpJgt92mlPBWbIj9U9F5r54xmRf2fk">
```

security.yaml

```php
firewalls:
        static_pages:
            pattern:    ^/static
            security:   false

        oauth_token:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/token
            security:   false

        oauth_authorize:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/auth
            security:   false
            # Add your favorite authentication process here

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            user_checker: security.user_checker
            form_login:
                provider: app_user
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: app_homepage
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            guard:
                provider: app_user
                entry_point: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\GoogleAuthenticator
                    - App\Security\FacebookAuthenticator
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
```

RegistrationController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Identity;

use App\Controller\BaseController;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\RegisterType;
use App\Security\AuthenticationManager;
use App\Util\UserManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

/**
 * @Route("/register")
 *
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="app_registration_register")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserManager $userManager
     * @param AuthenticationManager $authenticationManager
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request, UserManager $userManager, AuthenticationManager $authenticationManager): Response
    {

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $form = $this->createForm(RegisterType::class, $user, [
            'method' => Request::METHOD_POST
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if ($userManager->checkIfUserExists($user)) {
                $form->addError(new FormError('This email is already used.'));

                return $this->render('Registration/register.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                ));
            }

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            $authenticationManager->authenticate($user);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_homepage');
        }

        return $this->render('Registration/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Tell the user to check their email provider.
     *
     * @Route(path="/check-email", name="app_registration_check_email")
     *
     * @param Request     $request
     * @param UserManager $userManager
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function checkEmailAction(Request $request, UserManager $userManager): Response
    {
        $email = $request->getSession()->get('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');

        if (empty($email)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('app_registration_register'));
        }

        $request->getSession()->remove('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
        $user = $userManager->findUserByEmail($email);

        if (is_null($user)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('app_security_login'));
        }

        return $this->render('Registration/check_email.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route(path="/confirm/{token}", name="app_registration_confirm")
     *
     * Receive the confirmation token from user email provider, login the user.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param string $token
     * @param UserManager $userManager
     *
     * @return Response
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function confirmAction(Request $request, string $token, UserManager $userManager): Response
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);
        if (is_null($user)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist', $token));
        }

        $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_registration_confirmed');
    }

    /**
     * Tell the user his account is now confirmed.
     *
     * @Route(path="/confirmed", name="app_registration_confirmed")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function confirmedAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        return $this->render('Registration/confirmed.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'targetUrl' => $this->getTargetUrlFromSession($request->getSession()),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param SessionInterface $session
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    private function getTargetUrlFromSession(SessionInterface $session): ?string
    {
        $key = sprintf('_security.%s.target_path', $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getProviderKey());

        if ($session->has($key)) {
            return $session->get($key);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

RegisterType.php

```php
<?php


namespace App\Form;


use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class RegisterType
 *
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => 'Email',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'forms-area__label'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Email',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('username', null, [
                'label' => 'Name',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'forms-area__label'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Name',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'options' => [
                    'attr' => [
                        'autocomplete' => 'new-password',
                    ],
                ],
                'first_options' => [
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'label_attr' => [
                        'class' => 'forms-area__label'
                    ],
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Password'
                    ],
                ],
                'second_options' => [
                    'label' => 'Retype password',
                    'label_attr' => [
                        'class' => 'forms-area__label'
                    ],
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Retype password'
                    ],

                ],
                'invalid_message' => 'Password mismatch',
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'csrf_token_id' => 'registration',
        ]);
    }

    // BC for SF < 3.0

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }
}
```

register.html.twig

```html
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'forms-area__form'}}) }}
                    {% if not form.vars.valid %}
                        <div style="text-align: left;padding: 10px;color: #ec3c3ce6;background-color: #ffe4c485;margin-bottom: 20px;border-radius: 3px;">
                            {{ form_errors(form) }}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="forms-area__field forms-area__field--icon">
                        {{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr': {'class': 'forms-area__input'}}) }}
                        {{ form_label(form.username) }}
                        <div>{{ form_errors(form.username) }}</div>
                        <svg class="icon icon-add-user forms-area__field-icon">
                            <use href="{{ asset('assets/images/svg/symbol/sprite.svg#add-user') }}"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="forms-area__field forms-area__field--icon">
                        {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'forms-area__input'}}) }}
                        {{ form_label(form.email) }}
                        <div>{{ form_errors(form.email) }}</div>
                        <svg class="icon icon-email forms-area__field-icon">
                            <use href="{{ asset('assets/images/svg/symbol/sprite.svg#email') }}"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="forms-area__field forms-area__field--icons">
                        <div class="forms-area__field-body">
                            {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, {'attr': {'class': 'forms-area__input'}}) }}
                            {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
                            <div>{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}</div>
                            <svg class="icon icon-padlock forms-area__field-icon">
                                <use href="{{ asset('assets/images/svg/symbol/sprite.svg#padlock') }}"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <svg class="icon icon-eye forms-area__field-icon-helper js-psw-field-toggle">
                                <use href="{{ asset('assets/images/svg/symbol/sprite.svg#eye') }}"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="forms-area__field forms-area__field--icons">
                        <div class="forms-area__field-body">
                            {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, {'attr': {'class': 'forms-area__input'}}) }}
                            {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
                            <div>{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}</div>
                            <svg class="icon icon-padlock forms-area__field-icon">
                                <use href="{{ asset('assets/images/svg/symbol/sprite.svg#padlock') }}"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <svg class="icon icon-eye forms-area__field-icon-helper js-psw-field-toggle">
                                <use href="{{ asset('assets/images/svg/symbol/sprite.svg#eye') }}"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="forms-area__footer-summary">
                        <p class="forms-area__notification">Passwords are case-sensitive, and must be at least 8 characters in length, and contain a number or special character</p>
                        <button class="forms-area__btn btn btn--grad btn--animated btn--sm" type="submit" name="send-data">Send to Email</button>
                    </div>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
```

спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы заключалось в том чтоб прописать session path:

```yaml
# config/packages/framework.yaml
session:
  save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажите токен явно `{{ form_row(form._token) }}`, если не поможет, то перед закрывающим тегом формы добавьте `{{ form_rest(form) }}`.

Надеюсь вам это поможет.